# Azure Search using wildcard in Lucene query returns unexpected results

Tags: azure, lucene, wildcard

*Please ignore the whitespace you see between title parenthesis.*

Below query returns **94** records: (Expectation: titles containing word **`pregnancy`**) - ***PASSED***

`title:(`**`pregnancy`**`)&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&$skip=0&$top=12`

Below query returns **3** records: (Expectation: titles containing word **`pregnant`**) - ***PASSED***

`title:(`**`pregnant`**`)&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&$skip=0&$top=12`

Below query returns **97** records: (Expectation: titles containing words that start with **`preg`**) - ***PASSED***

`title:(`**`preg*`**`)&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&$skip=0&$top=12`

Below query returns **3** records: (Expectation: titles containing words that start with **`preg`** and end with **`nt`**) - ***PASSED***

`title:(`**`preg*nt`**`)&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&$skip=0&$top=12`

Below query returns **3** records: (Expectation: titles containing words that start with **`preg`** and end with **`t`**) - ***PASSED***

`title:(`**`preg*t`**`)&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&$skip=0&$top=12`

Below query returns **0** records:  (Expectation: titles containing words that start with **`preg`** and end with **`cy`**) - ***FAILED*** - Excepted at least **94** records

`title:(`**`preg*cy`**`)&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&$skip=0&$top=12`

Below query returns **0** records: (Expectation: words that start with **`preg`** and end with **`y`**) - ***FAILED*** - Excepted at least **94** records

`title:(`**`preg*y`**`)&$count=true&queryType=full&searchMode=any&$skip=0&$top=12`

I read these two articles:
[Lucene query syntax in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search) and [How full text search works in Azure Search](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-lucene-query-architecture)

I am almost ready to believe the * in above queries acts like a prefix operator, meaning, finding the words that start with "preg", instead acting like a wildcard search indicator.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how to rewrite my queries to include titles that "start with certain" characters, and "end with certain" characters in the search results?  Can I not use wildcard character * for this purpose?

Please do not get hung up on the term "pregnancy", I have used other words for searches as well, like "potato", "tomato", "exercise", "cancer", etc.

Answer (score 0):

I had created a ticket for Microsoft.  Their suggestion was to change Azure Search Analyzer from "English Lucene" to "English Microsoft".

The explanation was that "English Lucene" automatically stems last character from a word.

You can see the differences here: [Azure Search Analyzer Demo](http://alice.unearth.ai/)

Whether this is correct approach or not, it is debatable.  Changing the analyzer did serve my purpose... for now.

[image]